# How uber's Api treats timestamps

Tags: datetime, timezone, unix-timestamp, timezone-offset, uber-api

Creating a new ride reminder requires **event's time** and **reminder_time** in UNIX timestamp.
https://developer.uber.com/docs/ride-requests/tutorials/ride-reminders/introduction#create-a-new-reminder

```js
{
  "reminder_time": 1477397303,
  "phone_number": "+1234567890",
  "event": {
    "name": "Coding night Test",
    "location": "AMC Metreon 16",
    "latitude": 37.784223,
    "longitude": -122.403462,
    "time": 1477411703
  }
}
```

I am creating a new reminder and providing the event time and reminder_time in UNIX timestamp according to my time zone(I have them calculated and both these times are in same TZ).

My question is how Uber's interpret these provided times?

**Scenario :** Event's Time is in different time zone and user setting up reminder is in different TZ.

According to uber docs only following info is provided on timezones:

> Timezones: All timezones in the API are expressed as a UTC epoch and it is the responsibility of the client to localize.

- How can i handle this? Do i have to convert both event_time and & reminder_time into a standard timezone like GMT/UTC, and pass these timestamps.
- How uber will interpret these given timestamps and send user reminder at the correct time when user expected that to be sent.
- Do Uber consider provided **phone_number** in calculating timezone and sending notification/sms to user according to her TZ.

So far I am only being able to get sms at the correct time when i sent both timestamps calculated in my TZ.

Comment: Unix timestamps are always UTC based.  What kind of input or output are you aiming for?  What programming language?  As for phone number, no - that is not related to time zone at all.  It's possible to use the lat/lon to derive time zone, but not phone number.

Comment: You should convert both times to utc as unix time is utc. You can localize for the user to converting to their local time for display.

Answer (score 0):

You should convert all times to utc as unix time == utc. You can localize for the user to converting to their local timezone when displaying to the user.